# DomainName & Developing Time

Tags: asp.net

is there any way to develop a website by a domain name in win 7 (or even win2008)?
I mean in develop time (in VS 2010) when I press F5 , I see my application under a real domain name like : [MyDomainName.com] instead of [localhost\ProjectName]

Thank you very much for your feedbacks

Comment: why do you want to do that under domain name any specific reason? You have to host your domain so that it can resolve, you cannot do that using your local system unless you set it up as a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid hard coding your urls so that the domain can change without breaking your code.  instead of building url with the domain information, simply build them as relative links (  ~/pagename.aspx instead of localhost/project/pagename.aspx ), that way it never matters where the site is published.  If you need to build full url's for things that need a full url, you can use the following code to get the current location of the site.

```
Private m_serverName As String = ""

Private Sub WebForm1_InitComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.InitComplete

  Dim tempPort As String = Context.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT").Trim

  If tempPort = "80" Or tempPort = "443" Then
     m_serverName = Context.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
  Else
     m_serverName = String.Format("{0}:{1}", Context.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"), tempPort)
  End If

  If Request.IsSecureConnection = True Then
     m_serverName = String.Format("https://{0}", m_serverName)
  Else
     m_serverName = String.Format("http://{0}", m_serverName)
  End If
End Sub
```

Then when you need to build a url, use something like this:

```
Dim tempUrl As String = String.Format("{0}/pagename.aspx", m_serverName)
```